# Proving uniqueness of group identity element

Tags: group-theory, proof, theorem-proving

Start, as in the *Mathematica 11.3* documentation, with:

```
   groupTheory = {ForAll[{a, b, c}, g[a, g[b, c]] == g[g[a, b], c]], 
                  ForAll[a, g[a, e] == a], ForAll[a, g[a, inv[a]] == e]}
```

The result I want *Mathematica* to prove is the uniqueness of the identity `e`:

```
   uniqueIdentityThm = ForAll[f, Implies[ForAll[x, g[x, f] == x], f == e]]
```

If I try...

```
   FindEquationalProof[uniqueIdentityThm, groupTheory]
```

... then I get a surprising error message:

```
... FindEquationalProof: Invalid specification of propositions ....and axioms..
```

Do I have a syntax error I'm not seeing?

Or is the issue simply the presence of `Implies`?

Note that the general form of what I'm trying to do is OK, for example:

```
   inverseIsInvolution = ForAll[x, inv[inv[x]] == x
   FindEquationalProof[inverseIsInvolution, groupTheory]
```

This *does* yield a `ProofObject`, which can be examined, e.g., by evaluating the preceding result with argument `"ProofNotebook"`.

Comment: Does it work if you replace `Implies` with the equivalent `Nand[#1, Not[#2]]&`?

Comment: @PatrickStevens: No, and not with the equivalent `Or[Not[#1],#2]&`, which I had already tried.

Answer (score 7):

Let us consider the axioms for a group:

```
groupTheory={ForAll[{a,b,c},g[a,g[b,c]]==g[g[a,b],c]],
  ForAll[a,g[a,e]==a],
  ForAll[a,g[a,inv[a]]==e]};
```

As shown in the question, Murray's command for proving that the right identity is unique:

```
FindEquationalProof[Implies[ForAll[a, g[a, f]==a], e==f], groupTheory ]
```

fails with a message that there is an invalid specification of propositions and axioms. This suggests (I am not sure at all) that the first argument of `Implies` is considered as an axiom, that should be placed in the second argument of `FindEquationalProof`. Anyway, the unicity can be shown with *Mathematica* in the following way:

```
FindEquationalProof[e==f, Append[groupTheory, ForAll[a, g[a, f]==a] ]]

(* ProofObject[Logic: EquationalLogic   Steps: 10 ...] *)
```

And for sake of completeness, *Mathematica* can show that any right identity is also a left identity:

```
FindEquationalProof[ForAll[a, g[e, a]==a], groupTheory ]

(* ProofObject[Logic: EquationalLogic   Steps: 11 ...] *)
```